# Performance anonymize production data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a production database with ~1000 users. For testing purposes we use an anonymous version of this db on development and staging servers. But for security reasons we don't want to have our actual production data with laying around in 5 different places.

Because of this we have devised a simple script:

```
user_count = 0
User.all.find_each(batch_size: 1000) do |user|
  user.email = "user#{user_count}@example.com"
  user.password = '123456'
  user.save!
  user_count += 1
end
```

The problem with this is that the performance is awful. It already takes minutes to run, and we expect/hope that the number of users will grow.

We need the users to still have unique emails after the script.

Any solutions to make this happen a little quicker?

(I am not sure if it is relevant but we use authlogic for auth)

Comment: I don't really understand the idea of populating DB with real users data, as it could be easily done using seeds. Anyway, if you want to improve your little script, just skip 'all' part from query. Just use User.find_each. As 'all' will instantiate all records for the table.

Comment: We don't know enough about your environment. What is the DB hosted on? What is the DB schema? What is the network latency and throughput? In general, on a well designed database hosted on good hardware with a decent network, DB I/O is extremely fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this. It reduced the time from 160 seconds to 0.09 seconds

```
u = User.last
u.password = '123456'
User.update_all("email = CONCAT('user', ID, '@example.com'), crypted_password = '#{u.crypted_password}', password_salt = '#{u.password_salt}'")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, You want a database populated with production like data, but with random values in few fields for test environment.

You can directly run MySql queries for such purpose, which will be considerably fast. You can use `MD5` function to generate random values, assuming you have a unique column `id`:

```
UPDATE users set email = CONCAT(MD5(id),"@example.com"), password = rand(a big number);
```

This will update users with random email ids, You can use other combinations with MySql functions such as `CONCAT`, `rand` to set email accordingly.

Comment: I don't want the data to be random. I want it to be "production like". I want to perserve the distribution over different user types and so on.

Comment: In that case ,You can update only name and password field, using a database UPDATE query, instead of writing a script.

Comment: The users are also owners of different resources in the application. I want to keep those relationships as well...

Comment: Yes, but i am unsure about how to write the query in such a manner as to update each user with a unique email in a single query.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: We don't know the DBM, but using ActiveRecord vs. writing direct queries is hardly likely to be the problem. More likely it's the code around the section that does the query. ActiveRecord and Sequel (both good ORMs) are capable of writing excellent SQL, but the programmer has to use their capabilities correctly. And the database has to be designed correctly. And hosting of the DB is very important. None of that is known yet. Directly writing the SQL only reduces one of the main advantages of using an ORM, which is portability.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are pulling all of your users and updating them each one and a time. I recommend that you instead just update the database directly. ActiveRecord will allow you to perform straight SQL so something like this would likely work depending on how you are encrypting your passwords and what field your password is actually stored in:

```
password = my_password_hasher '123456'
sql = "UPDATE users SET email=concat('user', id, '@example.com'), password_digest = #{password}"
User.connection.execute sql
```

Comment: ActiveRecord is capable of generating that same query but can do so in a portable manner. I'm not sure there's an advantage to writing the query manually. Not iterating over the database will be a lot bigger speed-up, and allowing AR to generate the query will retain its advantage.